# Cant launch program on Galaxy Nexus 7

Tags: android, nexus-7

I'm simply trying to launch the base program that you create with any new android project in eclipise. I've followed the steps Google provide at [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) and I have enabled the developer options on the tablet itself.

My device is the brand new Nexus 7 and I've updated it so that it is the latest version of Android 4.3 but when I go to launch the app as an Android Application it says that no AVD can be found. However, according to the linked documentation I don't need one.

I've checked the android device chooser and there is nothing in the "choose a running Android Device" table.

Has anyone else experienced any issues with launching and debugging an app on their Nexus?

Comment: Have you installed the ADB drivers?

Comment: +1 Very good question that clearly states the problem and what you have tried.